# Recentering an unbalanced time predictor for mixed models

Tags: r

I would like to recenter an unbalanced time predictor in a mixed model so that the intercept reflects end of treatment.

For example:

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
Time <- c(0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3)
Before <- data.table(ID,Time)
Before

ID Time
1    0
1    1
2    0
2    1
2    2
3    0
3    1
3    2
3    3
```

I would like to get this:

```
Recenter <- c(1,0,2,1,0,3,2,1,0)
After <- data.table(ID,Time, Recenter)
After

ID Time Recenter
1    0        1
1    1        0
2    0        2
2    1        1
2    2        0
3    0        3
3    1        2
3    2        1
3    3        0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to reverse `Time` within each `ID`. This is what you need:

```
Recenter <- unlist(with(Before, tapply(Time, ID, rev)), use.names = FALSE)
```

by applying `rev` function to unbalanced / ragged array using `tapply`.